# In VBA Getting False on Comparing two equal Double values

Tags: excel, vba

Getting false on comparing two equal Double values (as shown in image), don't know why I'm getting this, tried to debug, but stuck.
In VBA (IN Excel)

[image: VBA equal values false result]

Comment: Try evaluating Draught.value = Draught2.value ?

Comment: Needs some context - where are the values coming from?

Comment: both the values are coming from the Cells in an Excell Sheet,  Draught, Draught2 are the variables of  Double type,

Comment: And where do the cell values come from?  You just typed "6" in each cell, or ?

Comment: yes, the typed values and cell data format is Number, showing in the Excel